# Console errors working with npm+gulp

Tags: windows, npm, gulp

I went to my `node_modules/.bin` directory that console: `gulp watch` and retrieve `throw new Error('`libsass`bindings not found. Try reinstalling`node-sass`?');`. So I stackoverflow it and found possible solution to `npm rebuild node-sass`. But I'm getting this error with it:
[image]

And here I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for current issue was in package.json wrong config:

```
    "gulp-sass": "^1.2.0",
```

had to be changed for:

```
    "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0",
```

and `gulp watch` working as expected:
[image]